# Serializers vs. Forms. How can I have both?

Tags: django, forms, serialization

Salut friends,

I have been working with Django on a project for over a year now, and this project doesn't quite have forms (just a few). The way it is done is without Django Rest Framework, simple crispy forms, which are validated when the POST arrives at the corresponding view.

A month ago, I started to work on a different project, much bigger, that in the greatest part relies on forms. This project uses Django Rest Framework, serializers + viewsets, and renders forms through DRF serializers.

After attaining a certain understanding of all the validations that can be done with DRF serializers, I started to imagine it'd be a good idea to bring serializers and viewsets to my older project in order to enjoy the better structure offered by DRF.

Here is my question: Can (crispy) forms and serializers work well together? Is it better to render my forms with DRF if deciding to stick with DRF? I saw a couple of people who use both, but it is unclear to me at this point. Is there a more standard way to do so, which is used by a majority?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I use DRF with Crispy Forms, I started doing so from the start of using DRF because they recommended it in their documentation...

> Requirements REST framework requires the following:
>
> - Python (2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5)
> - Django (1.8, 1.9, 1.10)
>
> The following packages are optional:
>
> - coreapi (1.32.0+) - Schema generation support.
> - Markdown (2.1.0+) - Markdown support for the browsable API.
> - django-filter (0.9.2+) Filtering support.
> - ***django-crispy-forms - Improved HTML display for filtering.***
> - django-guardian (1.1.1+) - Object level permissions support

Comment: Tim, thanks for your response. Could provide me an example?

Comment: Sure.  Crispy is mainly used to help the filtering side, but if you want some code examples of forms using DRF I can post some for you.  It won't be til tomorrow though as I'm not in front of a computer right now just my phone.  Let me know exactly what you need an example of and I'll do my best.

Comment: Can haz any xample plz? Tnx

Comment: Love to see a good example of this.